# Errors when installing python3-dev on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install some Python modules and I get errors with the python3-dev.

I do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

and I get the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3.8-dev (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev
```

and I got the errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libpython3-dev : Dépend: libpython3.8-dev (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How could I solve this problem? It is driving me crazy since two days ago!

Answer (score 2):

Here is some steps to help you out with your issue :

1- Try to enable ***restricted*** & ***universe*** repositories.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository universe 
 sudo add-apt-repository restricted
```

2- Make an OS update :

```
sudo apt update
```

3- Install **software-properties**

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

4- Add ***Deadsnakes*** repo :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

5- Cleanup the packages database :

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

6- Resolve depedencies problems :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

7- Install your package :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks but I get exactly the same errors

Comment: could you put the output of sudo dkpg --configure -a

Comment: I don't get any output

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962402/dpkg-error-pycompile-not-found/58980420#58980420

Answer (score 1):

Found an easier answer.

apt install aptitude

aptitude install vim    (or something that needs libpython)

say No (n) to the first question, it will then offer you another alternative to reinstall python3.8 for you.

Solved!